# Return number of users for each month by type

Tags: mysql, sql, select, count

I do not know how possible this is:

I have a database in (SQLfiddle)[http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d7a8f/3], from that database I want to return the following :

I want to return number of user created in each month based on their type.
There are four role in my database (administrator, No Role, super user, User).

Just to elaborate on my query this is how I want the information to be like:
e.g. 
[image: SQL Picture]

January 2016, 4 , 3 ,5, 8,20.
 January 2015 would be the month, 4 is for administrators, 3 for No role, 5 for super user, 8 for Users, and 20 for the overall total.
The user type must be sorted in ascending order.

I have tried the following:

```
Select DATE_Format(TIMESTAMP,' %b %Y') AS MONTH,Usertype,count(UserID)
from user
group by Month,Usertype
```

Comment: It's generally best to handle issues of data display in the presentation layer, if that's available

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a bunch of `count` functions on `case` expressions that break up the data to the respective roles:

```
SELECT   DATE_FORMAT(TIMESTAMP, '%b %Y') AS `month`,
         COUNT(CASE UserType WHEN 'Administrator' THEN 1 END) AS Administrator,
         COUNT(CASE UserType WHEN 'No Role' THEN 1 END) AS NoRole,
         COUNT(CASE UserType WHEN 'Super User' THEN 1 END) AS SuperUser,
         COUNT(CASE UserType WHEN 'User' THEN 1 END) AS `User`
FROM     `user`
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(TIMESTAMP, '%b %Y')
```

Comment: *The user type must be sorted in ascending order.*

Comment: Splash it is fine, I can do that now

Comment: @splash58 skipped that, thanks for pointing it out. Since the user types are static in the query, I just replaced `NoRole` to come before `SuperUser`.

Comment: I understood that they should be ordered by counts of users but names :)